# Can an LED starve an MCU of current?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage

I have what is probably a really stupid question, so please don't laugh at me. Say I have a circuit with a microcontroller and an LED. This circuit is powered by two AAA batteries in series for a total supply voltage of 3V. If the LED has a forward voltage of 2V, does that mean that it could starve the MCU of voltage and cause it to reset?

My thinking is that 3V - 2V = 1V, which wouldn't be enough to run the MCU. What am I missing?

Clarification: I'm not connecting the LED in series before the MCU Vcc pin of course. The LED is driven by one of the output pins of the MCU.

Comment: Do you have a current limiting resistor in series with the LED? Because if not, then your answer is yes. Well, your answer is yes anyway because it's rather vague and definitely "can" happen.

Comment: Yes, I have a 220 ohm resistor between the LED and ground.

Comment: Could you provide a small schematic showing your connection points and wiring?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is not for this specific circuit which is just the output pin of an Atmega328 driving an LED that has a 220-ohm resistor. I'm just trying to understand how it is that the LED uses up 2V and that the MCU can still run. I must be missing something fundamental, because what does the "forward voltage" in the LED datasheet refer to otherwise?

Comment: To put it another way: How does the MCU have enough voltage left to operate if it has to drive a 2V LED? Obviously it does, because the circuit works. I just don't understand how.

Comment: The forward voltage of the diode is going to change with the forward current. There should be a slope given on the datasheet. You don't need all of those 2V to start trickling current across it.

You're reasoning is valid for an ideal diode but a real one will trickle on. I'm actually spec'ing out one today:

http://datasheet.octopart.com/LTL-4233-R1-Lite-On-datasheet-99868.pdf

I'm not sure your exact diode but look at the last page of that datasheet.

Comment: I'm sorry, refer to Peter's answer. I think you're getting voltage and current mixed up in your head. Think of the 3V as a maximum rating. Anything that needs up to 3V will work. What would "starve" is the current output. An MCU is only rated up to X milliamps and won't run anything properly above that. Exceeding X could damage or "starve" your MCU.

Comment: @user29920: The CPU has VDD and VSS pins which allow the battery voltage to reach it without having to go through the LED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your circuit is something like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMtrgY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the normal way of connecting things, and the LED will not "starve" the microcontroller of power.

The microcontrooler will always see 3 volts from the batteries.  When the micro sets the ouput high to turn on the LED, The micro will deliver current from its output pin which will flow through the LED and resistor.  There will be about 2 volts across the LED, and about 1 volt across the 220 ohm resistor.

Comment: How can the 220 ohm resistor have 3 volts across it?

Comment: I think that Peter meant 1V.

Comment: @ChrisL: Yes, there will be 1 volt across the resistor (I've worked for too long with 5 volt logic - can't get used to thes new-fangled low voltage stuff...)

Answer (score 2):

Circuits in Parallel, have the same voltage, but have different current going through them.

Circuits in Series, have the same current, but have different voltage levels at different points in the circuit.

In your question, the MCU and the LED+Resistor are in parallel. The Led and resistor are in series. The Forward voltage is what the LED needs to work, and the Resistor drops the rest of the voltage. So if your LED is 2v, the LED takes up 1v, In that circuit only.

Just think of the led and the mcu as simple resistors.

But it is a bit more complex. You see the MCU as a single thing. It is not. It is an Integrated Circuit. A very small, and complex set of circuits including series and parallel, and transistors.

What you see:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftVMZ4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But on the inside, the circuit is in parallel. As an simple analogy, the output pin is a transistor pulling the pin high, making a connection to VCC (the battery). It makes the output pin parallel to the MCU's logic circuit, not series.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmCKcP.png)</sup>

Comment: I understand what you're saying. How would one "know" that the MCU and LED+Resistor are in parallel? Because to me it doesn't look obvious by looking at e.g. Peters schematic below. Do you just know from experience?

Comment: @user29920 I updated the answer just now to show that. Its basically because a MCU is not a single part, but a very very small circuit board with thousands of circuits and transistors. The real parts are way more complex, but this is generally what happens.